# Counting function for the number of zeros of a continuous positive function?

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, asymptotics, roots

Let $f(x)$ within $x\in[a,b]$ an absolute continuous function with

- $f(x)\geq0$
- $f(x_m)=0$ for all absolute minima $x_m$
- no other *zeros* than at $x_m$

I am trying to define a *counting function* for the $x_m$ within $x\in[a,b]$ which delivers at highest possible accuracy at any $a\lt x \lt b$, the number of *zeros* $x_m$ with $a \lt x_m \lt x$. For this purpose I *try* to construct a counter function, starting with the form:

$$\kappa=\int_a^x \exp\left(-\varepsilon f(t)\right)\mathrm dt$$

It seems that for *sufficient* large $\varepsilon$ we can achieve that $exp(-\varepsilon f(x))$ approximates *zero* for all $x\neq x_m$, and $exp(-\varepsilon f(x))=1$ for $x_m$.

However, I am still quite struggling, how to tailor $\kappa$ to its final form, which should deliver the number of $x_m$. Two major open questions are:

- **How can I norm the integral, so it delivers at the end the correct numbers?** - I guess, one must devide it by some norm.
- **How shall $\varepsilon$ be mathematically defined to ensure accuracy of the result?** - It looks to me a quite vague formulation to say for instance only $\varepsilon f(x)\gg 0$. I would much prefer to have a kind of *big* $\mathcal O$ formulation or stronger constraints for $\varepsilon$.

I would appreciate your support to find the final formulation of a mathemtically well formed counting function. Of course, any helpful references would be also welcome.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: yes that is of course correct, it is repetitive indeed. Just trying to be over-detailed may be.

Comment: Following the dialogue with Ilya, I understand that the Integral *Ansatz* does not work for the purpose of counting the zeros/peaks. Consequently the bold marked questions can not be answered under the circumstance above. The Lebesque measure does not allow an integration as such - a similar case as with an integration of *Dirac* pulses. However, the answer by Ilya helped us enormousely to tailor change the *Ansatz* for alternative functions etc. So I Believe, that his answer is definitly a good guiding answer under circumstances. I will Close the case and check his answer green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't any non-negative continuous function on $[a,b]$ satisfy the conditions given in the last two bullets? Also, using $\varepsilon$ for something a priori big is touche.

I also do not think that you can construct such a counting function using integral (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure): currently you are trying to approximate the *length* of $\{f = 0\}$, not the number of elements there. I'm pretty sure that it's not something you would like to do. The thing is that the number of zeros is a very unstable quantity: if you know $f$ precisely, why would you go for approximation of this number; if you do not know it precisely, that it may have $1000$ zeros or none at all, and you can't even conclude that from the approximation of $f$ that you have.

Comment: Ilya, I know $f(x)$ at any time precisely within this interval. I can also calculate exactly the zeros $f(x_m)$. However, I need still an analytic function that gives me the number of those zeros counted. The counting should not be done by my eyes nor by a machine, but through a counting function. I know it sounds strange, but how can I count the number of the zeros via an analytic function? One may ask why this guy needs that, although he has the zeros, but unfortunately, I do need that.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi: this function is $\kappa(x) = \gamma(\{f = 0\}\cap (a,x))$ where $\gamma$ is the counting measure.

Comment: Ilya - I understand your standpoint, which is a correct form and expression, of course. But it is not what I am looking for. If I take $f(x)$, I see for all my type of functions that $exp(\varepsilon f(x))$ shows thin peaks at the zeros and for the rest I have almost zeros. It looks realy like a cumb function with peaks at $x_m$. So there must be a way that I could Count the number of the peaks. Perhaps this additional information helps further. I would be even happy to deduct a counting function $\kappa(x)$, which is a step function accumulating the number of peaks (integral?!).

Comment: Sorry I saw a typo in the integral, a 'minus' was missing. Appologize everybody.

Comment: Once again, if you integrate against the Lebesgue measure, you are computing the length - any integral with peaks would approach zero in case the set of minima is finite, and will provide positive value only if such set is infinite - but in that case you don't care about the value of the integral either. You need to use the counting measure, or to trick it around using some other functions - but anyways it does not seem to be avoidable. If you could provide motivation for your question, perhaps it would be easier to help more.

Comment: Yes, but what type of other function?! The motivation comes from signal processing. But I am not going further as I dont want to change the way and approach.